# Why am I getting a seg fault when I try to push_back an item in C++?

Tags: c++, hashmap, hashtable, hashcode

I'm working on a hash table lab for my Data Structures class. I keep getting a set fault which I think is happening when I use the push_back() function within the insert function. However, I am not sure what is causing this error.

```
    using namespace std;

    HashTable::HashTable(int buckets) {
        this->buckets = buckets;
        vector<Entry>* table = new vector<Entry>[buckets];
    }


    Entry HashTable::insert(GameBoard board, int number) {
        int index = compress(board.hashCode());
        Entry entry = Entry(board, number);
        table[index].push_back(entry);
        return entry;
    }


    int HashTable::compress(int hashCode) {
        return (hashCode % buckets);
    }


    Entry::Entry(GameBoard board, int value) { 
        this->board = board; 
        this->value = value; 
    }


    int GameBoard::hashCode() {

        int hashVal = 0;

        for (int r = 0; r < DIMENSION; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < DIMENSION; c++) {
                hashVal = ((127 * hashVal) + board[r][c]) % 16908799;
            }
        }

        return hashVal;
    }
```

Comment: Is it the push_back call or is it the [] operator? I'm a little fuzzy about the legality of `vector<Entry>* table = new vector<Entry>[buckets];`, but segfaults often come out of bad array indexes.

Comment: `hashCode % buckets` does not yield a uniform distribution unless `buckets` divides the number of possible hashes. Keep that in mind.

Comment: Time to load up your debugger. (we can't do that for you from here)

Answer (score 5):

In code shown in your question:

```
HashTable::HashTable(int buckets) {
    this->buckets = buckets;
    vector<Entry>* table = new vector<Entry>[buckets];
}
```

you create a local variable `table` which is a pointer to `vector<Entry>` and then leak that memory. Then in `HashTable::insert` you try to access member variable `table` which is uninitialized.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. Where exactly is the memory leak and how would I fix it?

Comment: Good catch, probably OP hides a member `table` (as it seems he's using it later in other member functions). @UBears if you declared already `table` as a member of your class, then just use `table = new vector<Entry>[buckets]`, then don't forget to `delete[] table` in the destructor.

Comment: @UBears memory leak is exactly in code copied to my answer. Read my answer again, but I can repeat here: you create a local variable called `table` there.

Comment: @vsoftco That solved it. I declared table in my header and that was what was giving me the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    HashTable::HashTable(int buckets) {
        this->buckets = buckets;
        vector<Entry>* table = new vector<Entry>[buckets]; // this table is local to this function, also a memory leek.
    }
```

As I can see in your `HashTable` constructor, you are initializing a local `vector<Entry>* table` to your constructor.

```
    Entry HashTable::insert(GameBoard board, int number) {
        int index = compress(board.hashCode());
        Entry entry = Entry(board, number);
        table[index].push_back(entry);
        return entry;
    }
```

and I can see you are going to `push_back()` to some other `table` at `insert` method. The seg. fault occuses because you going to `push_back` to an uninitalized `table`.

Do you have any `vector<Entry>* table` in your `HashTable` class. If you have change your `HashTable::HashTable(int buckets)` to initialize that table as shown in below.

```
        HashTable::HashTable(int buckets) {
            this->buckets = buckets;
            table = new vector<Entry>[buckets]; // Init class attribute `vector<Entry>* table`
        }
```

If you don't you have any `vector<Entry>* table` in your `HashTable` class, add it to your class and use above `HashTable::HashTable(int buckets)`.

This will resolve your issue.